# how to retrieve the value from text field?

Tags: jquery

How to retrieve the value from text field?
 And how to concanate the value in jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var value = $('#textFieldId').val(); // jQuery
var otherValue = value + ' is now concatenated'; // basic JavaScript
```

Reference: [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [*Introduction to strings in JavaScript*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html)

Comment: Nice reference to the *introduction to strings*. +1

Answer (score 1):

To get a value of an input give it an id and use the following

```
var inp = $('#idofinputfield').val();
```

and to concatenate use the `+` sign

```
var inp1 = 'test';
var inp_concat = inp1 + ' ' + inp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the value:

```
var value = $('input#id').val();
```

Setting the value:

```
var value = $('input#id').val('newvalue');
```

Adding to the value:

```
var $input = $('input#id');
$input.val( $input.val() + ' something else' );
```

Note that the selector I've used specifies both the `tag` and the `id`.  Of course, you could simply use the `id` since it is unique (as long as your HTML is valid).  Adding the tag can help with readability if the id isn't semantically rich, which is why I've used it in the example.  If your input's id is descriptive, there's probably no need for it.